# AdressOf linked to other class?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a program for restaurants that will allow them to add and remove tables to the program.
My idea is that there is a button called 'add table' that will generate a button with its name as the table number and that the newly created button will have a function or sub in it (i'm not quite sure on this yet, work in progress)

The thing is that i have found how to dynamically add buttons but i'm confused on the AdressOf part.

Do i need to use the adressOf part to link the desired method or that done in another way?

```
Public Class Form_Create_Button

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CreateButton(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub CreateButton(TableNr As String, PersonNr As String)
    Dim Button As New Button With {.Left = 10, .Top = 10, .Text = TableNr, .Name = "Button" & TableNr}
    AddHandler Button.Click, AddressOf '...
    Main_Form.GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Button)
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`AddressOf` operato](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx)r to add an event handler programmatically. So you can use one handler for all of your buttons. You can use the `Sender` argument to identfiy a button:

```
Private Sub CreateButton(TableNr As String, PersonNr As String)
    Dim Button As New Button With {.Left = 10, .Top = 10, .Text = TableNr, .Name = "Button" & TableNr}
    AddHandler Button.Click, AddressOf TableClicked
    Main_Form.GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Button)
End Sub

Private Sub TableClicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs )
    Dim button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    Dim tableNumber As String = button.Name.Substring(6)
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Comment: So i can put any code i need in the TableClicked method and my dynamic buttons will all respond to that? correct?
Thx for the fast reply

Comment: @Vahx: Yes, you can put the logig here that should be executed when the user clicks one of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You're worried about using the same method with `AddHandler`, and then when that method is called you need to know which button was clicked. That's the `sender` argument is for in event handlers:

```
Private Sub CreateButton(TableNr As String, PersonNr As String)
    Dim Button As New Button With {.Left = 10, .Top = 10, .Text = TableNr, .Name = "Button" & TableNr}
    AddHandler Button.Click, AddressOf Table_Click
    Main_Form.GroupBox1.Controls.Add(Button)
End Sub

Private Sub Table_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim button As Button = TryCast(sender, Button)
    '...
End Sub
```

They only thing missing here is the PersonNr and TableNr data, but at this point it should be easy enough for you to attach those to the button themselves. If you need a push, one option is to inherit your own control from button with those additional fields.

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm not sure what you are trying to show me here. that i can do this without the AddHandler and AdressOf ? or are those added to the table_click method now?